# How to delete all rows with a specific Shading.BackgroundPatternColor (from a selected table)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to associate a shortcut key to a VBA macro that I can use on some tables of my Word document.
This macro should go through all rows of the selected table and remove those with a specific Shading.BackgroundPatternColor

I've tried the following code :

```
Sub DeleteRowWithShading()


Dim oRow As Word.Row

  For Each oRow In Selection.Rows
        If oRow.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -721354855 Then
            oRow.Delete
        End If
  Next oRow

End Sub
```

The loop through all rows of the table is correct but rows aren't deleted as expected.

I'm rather new to VBA so any help appreciated !

Comment: You can't use for each in this case, you have to iterate by an index and also count down.  The reason for this is that the indexing changes when you delete a row.  e.g. If you delete row 1 then row 2 becomes row 1.  How is the control variable supposed to know if you have deleted rows ?  If you count down then deleting row 5 doesn't change the numbering of row 4 etc.

Comment: This helped, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems occur when elements of a collection are deleted during a loop. The deletion removes the item from the collection, which throws the internal counting off.

There are two basic ways to work around this.

1) Work through the items from back to front. Since that which is being removed from the collection was at the end it doesn't throw the count off:

```
Sub DeleteRowWithShading()
    Dim oRow As Word.Row
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim nrRows As Long, rowCounter As Long
    Dim check As Long

    Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)
    nrRows = tbl.Rows.Count

  For rowCounter = nrRows To 1 Step -1
        Set oRow = tbl.Rows(rowCounter)
        If oRow.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -721354855 Then
            check = check + 1
            oRow.Delete
        End If
  Next
  Debug.Print "Nr of rows deleted: " & check

End Sub
```

2) Add the items to an array or custom collection during the first loop, then loop the array/collection to remove all the items (rows).

```
Sub DeleteRowWithShadingInArray()
    Dim oRow As Word.Row
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim RowsToDelete() As Variant
    Dim check As Long, itemNr As Long

    Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)
    itemNr = 0
    For Each oRow In tbl.Rows
        ReDim Preserve RowsToDelete(itemNr)
        If oRow.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -721354855 Then
            Set RowsToDelete(itemNr) = oRow
            itemNr = itemNr + 1
        End If
    Next

    itemNr = 0

    For itemNr = 0 To UBound(RowsToDelete)
            check = check + 1
            RowsToDelete(itemNr).Delete
    Next

    Debug.Print "Nr of rows deleted: " & check

End Sub
```